# Как показать только нужную часть картинки? HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, img

Хотел, чтобы картинка была наполовину ниже края документа, но он вместо этого расширяется.

Как это лучше сделать?

Может через `background-image`?

Желаемый результат:

[image: want]

Как сейчас:

[image: have]

Код:

```css
.skull {
  position: absolute;
  width: 864px;
  height: 988px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 250%;
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
```

```html
<img class="skull" src="img/skull.svg" alt="skull" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вам достаточно добавить "обертку" вокруг Вашего изображения и "обрезать" лишнее с помощью свойства `overflow`, со значением "hidden":

```css
body {
  height: 500px; 
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

div > img {
  display: block;
  margin-top: -100px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1011/400" />
</div>
```

*Позицию изображения в контейнере можно менять при помощи `margin` или продолжить использование абсолютного позиционирования (как в Вашем примере).*

*В данном примере использовано квадратное изображение 400px х 400px.*

Answer (score 4):

Используйте `overflow: hidden`

```css
.wrapper {
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.h400 {
  height: 400px;
}

.w200 {
  width: 200px;
}

.bg-green {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}

span {
  background-color: #c6c2c2;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="w200 h400 bg-green">
    Блок 200*400
  </div>
</div>
 Из-за того, что у <span>.wrapper</span> максимальная высота 100px, блок 200*400 обрезается и выглядит как 200*100
```

Вы можете также использовать background,
управлять положением картинки при помощи `background-position`

```css
*, *::after, *::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.block {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/556/556209.svg) no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 -70px;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
```